# Up vote and Down vote using codeigniter

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, model-view-controller

How do i add an up vote and down vote section on my forum using code igniter(Model View Controller architecture) and MongoDB PHP. I have tried it in SQL and now want to implement in MongoDB.

Comment: Have you tried something? Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Generally speaking you change all SQL stuff you have to MongoDB specific one and it's done. On a more serious note you need to provide way more information for anybody to answer your question.